# DJANGO: Dynamically forward to "next" after login with @user_passes_test

Tags: django, authentication, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to the django login setup.
And I've researched my way to something that seemed good and copied that.

I have discovered this decorator:
**@user_passes_test**

That helps me make sure people with the right access to my *"/dashboard"* page have logged in. 
After getting redirected to login the url is:

```
placeholder.it/login/?next=/dashboard/%3Fcvr%3D24256790
```

BUT the user always get send to:

```
placeholder.it/accounts/loggedin
```

insted of the next url.
*How come??*

This is some of my code:
**views.py**

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_staff, login_url='/accounts/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    cvr = request.GET.get('cvr', '')
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', { "cvr": cvr})    


def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)    


def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)    

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    

{% block content %}    

  {% if form.errors %}
    <p class="error">Sorry, that's not a valid username or password</p>
  {% endif %}    

  <form action="{% url 'auth' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="username">User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">    

    <input type="submit" value="login" />

  </form>    

  <br>
  Login to access all sites    

{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^accounts/auth/$', views.auth_view, name='auth'),
url(r'^dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

Appreciate any help <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decorator is sending the users who are not logged in to the `login` view. The login page has a form that posts to the `auth_view` view. The auth view explicitly redirects every logged in user to `/accounts/loggedin`.

You're redirecting users on your own, through the codes in `auth_view`. Your code doesn't respect the `next` query parameter (that the decorator is appending to the login url). Your code should read the value of the `next` parameter and put it in a hidden field inside the form. On the POST request to `auth_view`, you should read that value and redirect the user to that url.

Comment: This sound like it would work. I'm not sure how I would go about reading the value inside the form. Nor how to create the hidden field.

Or can I grap next form my view? 
If I do: `request.GET.get('next', '')` in my `auth_view` it just returns empty.

Comment: It would not be empty if the decorator sends you there.

Comment: I was refering to the login class from the decorator:
@user_passes_test(lambda u:u.is_staff, login_url='/accounts/login/')

So it had to be in the decorator, not `auth_view` 
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt decorator to handle if user has logged in or not
Import the following

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

And place the decorator above your function:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='next') 
def page(request):
```

Add this to your login template

```
input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"
```